# How can I modify and rebuild the Finnix ISO to include my own scripts?

Tags: livecd, iso

I've been using this live boot distro, [Finnix](http://www.finnix.org/) to do some installation work on several virtual machines.

I'd like to modify the ISO file to include a script I need to do installations. I've booted the virtual machine and gotten as far as copying the `/dev/cdrom` contents to a new Folder and modified it as needed.

Now I'd like to turn the plain folder back into a bootable ISO image and `nc` it back to my host machine for subsequent boots, modified with my additional content.

How can I turn the folder with the modified content back into a bootable ISO image?

Comment: 7 years question which has no good answer, If anyone still need this answer, I will spend time to write neat solution for this specifically based on Finnix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mkisofs to make the ISO

`mkisofs -o youriso.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -V youriso-live ~/isodistro/iso`

`-o` is the output file
`-b` is the boot image that it boots
`-c` is the boot catalog
and `~/isodistro/iso` is the path of the files

You can find the details on the switches here - http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/mkisofs-2.0.html

Answer (score 1):

I've not attempted this myself but I would start with the advice given in this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [Using SquashFS to edit a Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059/using-squashfs-to-edit-a-live-cd).

Specifically there is a Linux Journal article referenced in the Q&A, a 3 part Paranoid Penguin series titled: [Customizing Linux Live CDs](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/paranoid-penguin-customizing-linux-live-cds-part-i).

Also Ubuntu has some very good/detailed directions on doing this too:

- [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch)
- [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Though these aren't Finnix specific, they should help in answering your questions on how to attempt to do this.

There is also this guide which is Fedora base, but is pretty straightforward and looks to be only a few steps to do what you want. The article is titled: [Hacking a Fedora Live CD](http://voidmain.is-a-geek.net/redhat/fedora_10_live_cd_hacking.html).

#### Using an ISO tool

You could also try using a tool such as `mkisofs` (command line), its replacement - `genisoimage`, or [ISO Master](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/) (GUI).

#### Example

[image: isomaster ss]

Comment: Thank you this is a very considerate answer. I will go over all the resources.

Comment: @JamesAndino - you're quite welcome, let us know how you make out!

Comment: @JamesAndino - yes genisoimage is the new name. They're usually both available, but I've updated the A to include it.

Comment: Why Ubuntu? Finnix is based on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

7 years question but no appropriate answer for this which focuses on Finnix which OP is requested for. Now let's not talk about other distribution. Based on Finnix, taken from this post, you need to unpack filesystem.squashfs and modify your OS there then repack back filesystem.squashfs

Full working step is here:

https://www.dotpointer.ga/?section=notes&view=note&id_notes=164